# trigger for on join in laravel echo server with socket.io

Tags: laravel, vue.js, socket.io, laravel-5.5, laravel-echo

**[I am following this tutorial in Socket.io, vue.js and Laravel using laravel echo server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)**

I have the following code in Laravel-echo-server with socket.io, **I am not using Pusher and redis**

```
window.Echo.private('Room Name')    
.on('Channel Name', (e) => {
    //Code to receive the message
});
```

Do we have any option such that when new user join, the members get notified. I tried to search for on OnJoin, but seems like there is none.

**My Findings**

I saw this article: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#presence-channels but this is using Pusher/redis. But i am using socket.io with Laravel and vue.js

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're using Socket.io, you can use presence channels. The package `tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server` that you're using supports presence channels on the backend and also includes a Socket.io nodejs implementation.

Laravel Echo's library supports Socket.io so basically, you can use everything out of the box along with presence channels for your use case